# Gutenberg NPM doesn't do any changes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

The NPM when i created  some changes in blocks or something else .. the changes not working ,
and this my gutenberg.php

```
    function MyBlocks()
{
    wp_register_script('blocks-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/build/index.js', array('wp-blocks' , 'wp-editor' , 'wp-components' ));
    register_block_type('yusuf/custom-cta', array('editor_script' => 'blocks-js'));
    // register_block_type('yusuf/custom-pro', array('editor_script' => 'blocks-js'));
    // register_block_type("yusuf/statics" , array('editor_script' => 'blocks-js'));
  

}
add_action('init', 'MyBlocks');
```

I commented the blocks and still shows up ,
and removed it from build/index.js too , and still shows up ,
i want know why it happened with me !
And already the "NPM START" Runs

Comment: `npm start` builds the block/s you have defined in `src/index.js`, editing the `build/index.js` file will have no effect as  it will be rebuilt over it immediately. I suspect the issue could be in `src/index.js`, are you able to share how you are registering the blocks in `src/index.js`?

Comment: @S.Walsh the src/index.js just importing the blocks in it 
`
//Statics Counter Block!
import { staticsBlock } from "./Blocks/statics";
staticsBlock();

//About Us Section Block!
import { aboutusBlock } from "./Blocks/aboutus";
aboutusBlock();
`

Comment: So the two blocks 'yusuf/custom-pro' and 'yusuf/statics' are not imported in `src/index.js` and they are still showing in the Editor? Sounds like caching issue in browser. Trying stopping npm and clearing your browser cache to make sure you aren't seeing the old version, then restart the build with `npm start ` - is the issue still there?

Comment: @S.Walsh , it's always cashed like that , 
Btw thank you for helping .. I will be more attention in next times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's all In browser cache .. you can use a private browser or cleaning the browser cache every time you try to make any change .. and you will see your updates seems good